# Using typeof with generic method

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to be able to pass the type into a generic method where I only know the name of the type.

I want to do something like the following, but I am getting an error.

```
var type = typeof(name);
var result = MyGenericMethod<type>();
```

Is this possible?

Currently I am doing a switch statement, but this is less than ideal as I need to update each time I need to add a new class.

```
switch (name)
{
    case "TypeName1":
        result = MyGenericMethod<TypeName1>();
        break;
    case "TypeName2":
        result = MyGenericMethod<TypeName2>();
        break;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks I’ll take a look at this.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, this part

```
var type = typeof(name);
var result = MyGenericMethod<type>();
```

is not possible.

Maybe if you can describe what you are trying to achieve, it is possible to find a solution for your problem though.

Comment: Ok thank you for your comment, what I am trying to achieve is a short hand way to write the switch statement without having to have a separate case for each class, instead I can just pass in any class that is appropriate for the method and it will work, but by class name which is stored in a database table